# after validation successfully completed redirect to email.php page

Tags: php

Here i'm trying to send a contact form values to email id. I've posted contact.php page code. I've done server side validation on same page. After validation successfully completed it should redirect to email.php page. How should i do?

**Contact.php**

```
 <?php
    $errname = "";
    $errmotorcycle = "";
    //some codes

    if($_POST["contacts"] == "all")
    {
        // name validation
        if(empty($_POST["name"]))
        {
            $errname = '<span class="error">Should not be empty</span>';
        }
        else if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $_POST["name"]) === 0)
        {
            $errname = '<span class="error">Name must be from letters and spaces only</span>';
        }
        else
        {
            $errname = '';
        }
        // motorcycle validation
        if($_POST["typeofmotor"] == "empty")
        {
            $errmotorcycle = '<span class="error">You must select one option</span>';
        }
        //some codes
    }
 ?>

<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="contacts" value="all" />
<table width="980" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="281" height="40" class="rightalign">Name : </td>
    <td width="268"><input type="text" name="name" class="normal" value="<?php $_POST['name']; ?>" /></td>
    <td width="431" valign="middle"><?php if(isset($errname)) echo $errname; ?></td>
  </tr>
 //some codes
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you validate in one PHP request and then redirect to the email PHP script if successfull, what stops an attacker from directly calling your email PHP script bypassing any of your validations? Dont do this! Use include and process on the same request.

Comment: @ToBe : So shall i do the validation on email.php page?

Comment: As long as you do it on the same page as the sending (including a PHP is perfectly fine) you are good.

Answer (score 0):

After sending the eMail, you could redirect the browser like that:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/email.php');
die();
?>
```

If you choose that solution, please keep in mind that headers may only be sent *before* any content is sent to the browser.

Comment: not after sending an email. after validation successfully done it should redirect to email.php page...

Comment: Well, I normally do that this way: Post the form to the same file. If there is some flag to send a mail, validate the form. If validation is successful, send the eMail. If you don't want to have the part about sending mails inside that file, you could also include another file which handles sending the mail.

Comment: Dont validate on a different request as sending. Check my comment on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect to another script and use the POST vars as well, because they will be lost after the redirect. You can include the email.php script:

```
<?php
include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . "/email.php");
```